# How can I access a domain property using the property name?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain object with a property called date:

```
class Item implements Comparable{
  Date date
}
```

How can I access that date doing something like:

```
Item.list().each{
  Date d = it.get("date")
}
```

I know that I could do `Date d = it.date` but I want to be able to generically pick a property from my domain object and access it without using .property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..,.

```
Item.list().each {
    Date d = it.properties.get("date")
}
```

or

```
Item.list().each {
    Date d = it.getProperty("date")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should also work:

```
String propertyName = 'date'

Item.list().each {
    Date d = it."$propertyName"
}
```